How to Dynamically Fetch Azure Key Vault Secrets for Preproduction Environment in Azure Functions?
I’m working on an Azure Function that integrates with an external API and needs to handle secrets differently based on the environment:
In production, I use static configuration values loaded at startup (e.g., ClientId, ClientSecret, etc.).
In preproduction, I need to dynamically fetch these secrets from Azure Key Vault based on a unique identifier passed in the request (e.g., an identifier like GLN).
Scenario:

Production Environment: Secrets like ClientId, ClientSecret, and
SubscriptionKey are static and loaded from configuration at startup.
Preproduction Environment: Secrets need to be dynamically fetched
from Azure Key Vault at runtime based on the request’s identifier.

Code:
public async Task<Token> GetToken(string identifier)
{
    // Check if the token is cached
    if (_memoryCache.TryGetValue("token", out Token cachedToken) && cachedToken != null)
    {
        return cachedToken;
    }

    Token newToken;

    // Check if running in production (static secrets)
    if (IsProductionEnvironment())
    {
        newToken = await FetchTokenAsync(
            _configuration["ProdClientId"],
            _configuration["ProdClientSecret"],
            _configuration["ProdSubscriptionKey"]);
    }
    else
    {
        // For preproduction, fetch secrets dynamically from Key Vault
        var clientId = await FetchSecretFromKeyVaultAsync($"preprod-{identifier}-clientId");
        var clientSecret = await FetchSecretFromKeyVaultAsync($"preprod-{identifier}-clientSecret");
        var subscriptionKey = await FetchSecretFromKeyVaultAsync($"preprod-{identifier}-subscriptionKey");

        newToken = await FetchTokenAsync(clientId, clientSecret, subscriptionKey);
    }

    // Cache the token
    _memoryCache.Set("token", newToken, new MemoryCacheEntryOptions().SetAbsoluteExpiration(newToken.ExpiresAt));

    return newToken;
}

private async Task<string> FetchSecretFromKeyVaultAsync(string secretName)
{
    // Use KeyVault client to fetch secrets dynamically
    KeyVaultSecret secret = await _secretClient.GetSecretAsync(secretName);
    return secret.Value;
}

My Questions:

Is this approach of dynamically fetching secrets from Key Vault based on the request’s identifier the best practice, or is there a more efficient way to handle this?
How can I better structure my code to handle both static secrets for production and dynamic secrets for preproduction without duplicating logic?
Should I consider other Azure services (e.g., App Configuration) to streamline this approach?

Any advice on best practices for dynamically fetching secrets from Key Vault in this kind of scenario would be greatly appreciated!

Where is identifier coming from? Is it an environment variable / AppSetting?

No it is identifer coming from server call

Is Preproduction environment is on azure(other slots) or locally?



Is this approach of dynamically fetching secrets from Key Vault based on the request’s identifier the best practice, or is there a more efficient way to handle this?


Yes, This approach is only the way to fetch value from key vault in preproduction.


Should I consider other Azure services (e.g., App Configuration) to streamline this approach?


For Production environment, there is more secure way is there to fetch secrete from key vault using Key Vault Reference.
Environment Varibale Name = @Microsoft.KeyVault(VaultName=<keyvault's name>;SecretName=<secret's name>)
Check this MS Document.
Assign Function System Assigned Identity/User Assigned Identity RBAC role Key Vault Secrets User or Access policy in Key vault.
For Reference check this MS Document.
My code:
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace FunctionApp5
{
    public class Function
    {
        private readonly ILogger<Function> _logger;

        public Function(ILogger<Function> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        [Function("Function")]
        public IActionResult Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post")] HttpRequest req)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation(3009, "C# HTTP trigger TestOpenConnection function processed a request.");

           var secret = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("secrete_value");

            
           return new OkObjectResult($"The value of secrete is : {secret}");
        }
    }
}


OUTPUT:



